# Pointing Django to Different Template Directory

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-oscar

I am currently building a Django ecommerce site that is based on Django-Oscar. By default the latter comes with a basic Bootstrap theme and styles.

I moved these template files into

`project_root/templates/oscar`

It is my understanding that if I were to override these templates, it would override the original Oscar templates located in the virtualenv.

The next step is that I downloaded a different theme that I would like to use for the site.

In particular, I would like that theme to reside in

`project_root/templates/main_theme`

The trouble is that I cannot seem to get Django to pickup the templates from that directory. If I delete `project_root/templates/oscar`, it appears to resort back to the default Oscar templates.

If I place a `base.html` into `project_root/templates/` and make that `base.html` to be the main file of the new theme, it is displayed. However, I would still like to break it up into smaller files and have them "live" in a separate directory. How can I accomplish this? Is there a more prudent way of going about this?

Here are some relevant settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',
] + get_core_apps()

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

COMPRESS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

#This should be commented out in Development
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: why are you not making the changes in the oscar directory inside templates?? thats how you override default templates

Comment: The problem is that it does not seem to react to that. It still picks up the original Oscar templates. I tried creating a basic `base.html` inside `templates/oscar` and still got the default styles. The other part of the answer is that I was doing for organizational reasons.

Comment: inside templates/oscar/templates you will find a base.html, try to delete all the contents of that page and check if it gets rendered

Comment: I do not have `templates/oscar/templates`. I have `templates/oscar`.

Comment: What I do is rename `templates/oscar` to `templates/oscar1` and then create `templates/oscar` with a single `base.html` file that contains the layout of the desired template. With this in place, the Django still picks up the default Oscar template.

Comment: thats why the problem, you need to put templates/oscar/templates/ and inside this you need to put you overriding html code

Comment: I have just tried creating `templates/oscar/templates/base.html` with the new theme and it still shows the default Oscar template.

Comment: Does changing `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/oscar')` change things? `OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR` includes the oscar subdirectory, so you might have to as well.

Comment: @JacobHume You are correct. I resolved this a couple of days ago. I will post my code as an answer in case it helps someone later.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me. As it turned out, one needed to specify an additional entry in the `DIR` list of the `TEMPLATES` list.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),

            #re-route the search for templates into this custom template directory
            os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 'tshirt-theme'),

            #Uncomment the line below to restore the original Oscar template
            #OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also assign the different path to directories as variables :

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/local')
OSCAR_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/oscar')
TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

And in the Templates section of settings.py, assign these variables to Directory arg.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR, OSCAR_TEMP_DIR, TEMP_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now, you can put and use your templates from either

1. `project_dir/templates/local` OR
2. `project_dir/templates/oscar`OR
3. `project_dir/templates/` For Any template file that intersects
   both(eg: main base.html).

Just easier to read and cleaner code if you have to use multiple template directories.